# Why does washing machine not empty tub when finished, but instead start any program by emptying it?

Tags: washing-machine

After any program, including if I just soak some clothes and run an 8 minute centrifuging at full speed 1400rpm, somehow the washing cycle does not empty the tub. I know this, because, the next time I start a program, whether a full wash or just centrifuging, within the first few seconds, it let's out quite some water, I would guess 0.2 - 0.5 liters.

Is this an error, or is this normal behavior?

I believe this machine is of high quality amongst consumer washing machines, though around 8 years old. It's a Miele Novotronic W 1513.

As an experiment, I tried putting the drain hose into the shower, so that it sloped down all the way. The hose leaves the machine at the very top of the machine. This did not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The program probably empties the tub both before AND after a cycle. That way, if you terminate a cycle in the middle (e.g. power loss), and then start a new cycle, it will empty out any remaining water before it continues.

The few hundred ml of water that comes out at the beginning is probably because at the end all the water ran back down the pipe and pooled around the outlet, priming the pump and getting it ready for another blurp of pumping (technically speaking).

Comment: You are right, it does empty both before and after. But obviously, when emptying after, it does not empty fully. I still don't understand, why would it deliberately leave some water, why not pump IT ALL by the end of any program? What do you mean by "priming the pump"?

Comment: A lot of guessing here, but the outlet hose for your washing machine probably goes up a few feet before dumping into the standpipe. So, when the pump comes to the tail end of the water and starts to beat upon air, there's still water in the hose (probably a few liters). That water can't be pumped, and so runs back into the tub when the pump turns off. When the pump starts again, it has no backpressure from the (now missing) water in the hose, so the pump can really dig in, and does a (slightly) better job of evacuating the tub.

Comment: I checked that, and I've added this experience to my question text.

Comment: But, presumably the pump is at the BOTTOM of the washing machine tub, right? Otherwise it would have to be able to function with no water in the pump, which makes the pump more complex and expensive. So, after the pump there's a column of water up to where the hose leaves the washing machine (which is at the TOP of the machine, so that water doesn't just start draining out when you fill the tub). So, you still have a column of water after the pump.

Comment: I understand you, and it makes sense that this column of water can never leave the machine (though I do see smell problems with this, but let's ignore that). However, remember that when I start the machine, eg a centrifuging, it pumps out 0.5l of water within the first 5 seconds. And it has of course not taken any water in, so this IS leftover water from last cycle. So after a wash, it leaves some water, that it in fact IS ABLE to pump out.

Comment: Well, you don't believe my explanation; what's yours? ;)

Comment: Don't you agree, that if it is able to spit out 0.5l at the beginning of a wash, it should also be able to spit out the same 0.5l by the end of the last wash? :) I believe, that the machine is supposed to spit out the water by the end of the cycle, but it doesn't. And the reason for that could be the control circuit board. Maybe the controller gets wrong feedback from the pump or some sensor. Maybe it is timed to pump for a certain amount of time, and that is not enough. These are also only guesses :) Maybe I won't get an answer before a Miele technician visits this thread :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24823/discussion-between-daniel-griscom-and-mads-skjern).